# Want to use third party library "react-picky" for filterable multiselect component with React Material UI , but is inconsistent with Material Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

[image]Want to use third party library "react-picky" for filterable multiselect component with React Material UI ,but is inconsistent with Material Design styles

How to style any third party component consistent or with same look and feel like material design is there any way otherwise some components would be totally inconsistent with other React Material UI components

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You could use css and try to mimic the styles of React Material UI but it's going to be hard, especially because you don't have full control about the html of your multiselect component.

A much better and in my eyes clearner solution would be to use the Material UI Select which comes with material UI itsself. This way you don't break your design. It should also suit your needs as it has tons of different modes, including one for multiple values: 
https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/

You can also try something like this:

https://medium.com/@newswim/styling-third-party-components-with-styled-components-d82ac073d423 
with styled-components: https://www.styled-components.com/

Comment: You are right , and your suggestion is correct , however I am observing that components those are present for my use case in material ui means Autocomplete don't have scope of customization , also there is no "SELECT ALL" option in any of the components , where in if user would like to select all options

Comment: So i think in some situations there could be problem with Material UI ,because of its uniqueness and difficulty in adapting some third party library component customization ,Since you may need some third party components in your Project , So dependency on materail ui components becomes quite strong

Comment: I assume the only way would be to add custom css to these components as there is no other way I think

Comment: I was doing POC for my next enterprise project I was really excited for Material UI , But because of these limitations I would have to cancel this plan , it would be really tricky to adapt third party libraries according to Material Design

Comment: @VaibhavMittal View my answer, I may have found some sort of solution

Comment: @VaibhavMittal If my answer helped you make sure to accept it

Comment: I think the solution with styled components again creates dependency on styled components , if some one does not want to use styled components , Also even if use styled components I am not really able to understand that how can the animation effects of Material design can be achieved , Please give some working example that customize any component to Material UI look and feel , Article tells about styling third party component through Styled components in general instead of  Material UI look and feel ,

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not responsible for providing a working example. I provided all the information I have and that I could gather with quick research. Once again, I highly recommend you use as many of the provided material UI components as possible. If they don't suit your needs it'd be best to either not use the material UI framework or style these components with CSS so they look similar to those your framework provides. As far as I'm aware, there are no other options.

Comment: Css is the only option...i would use some other framework for now... Because of this limitation,